# How can I call a suspend function in Kotlin from capacitor?

Tags: android, kotlin, capacitor

I have an issue where I have native code written in Kotlin that I need to call as a Capacitor Pugin.
I can implement plugins to call normal functions just fine. However if I call a suspend function the app crashes and I get the following error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of arguments; expected 2, got 1

I tried calling a capacitor plugin function like so:

```
const {value} = await realmPlugin.initialize({ appId: 'myAppId' });
```

I expect to call my function and get the expected return, instead the app crashes and I get the error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of arguments; expected 2, got 1`

Comment: Calling a suspend function from JS can be a bit problematic and I found [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/6550) in capacitor and also [this thread](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-i-call-coroutines-from-javascript/12098/2) in Kotlin forums that may assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a wrapper in Kotlin with the call of your suspend function inside a coroutine scope. Just for example, with the `GlobalScope`:

```kotlin
fun initializePlugin(...) =
  GlobalScope.launch {
    realmPlugin.initialize(...)
  }
```